# How to Alter behavior of a console application depending on Scheduled or Manual execution?

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, console-application

I have a simple console application, which is executed via Task Scheduler twice a day. When it runs like this, the default input for the `Main()` method will be the current month and current year.

However, sometimes this task needs to be executed manually outside the schedule; in such a case, it should prompt the user for Year and month separately.

I know how to send the arguments while executing the application like this:

`myapplication.exe 2013 1`

I can check for the number of arguments and code accordingly.  But I want to prompt the user to enter month and year. How can we do this?  Thank you for the help.

Please suggest a better title for this post.

Comment: Are you simply looking for Console.ReadLine(); ?

Comment: @Haxx Yes, but only when executed manually.

Comment: added an example in nikola's answer. hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could introduce a special command line argument that would be only used when the app is executed via scheduler. If this argument is present, you would use current date, otherwise, you would prompt the user to enter the date for you.

E.g.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var yourFirstMagicNumber = -1;
        var yourSecondMagicNumber = -1;

        // Let's use the third argument as indicator that you need user input
        if (args.Length > 2 && "true".Equals(args[2]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter magic nr 1: ");
            var firstArgument = Console.ReadLine();
            yourFirstMagicNumber = Int32.Parse(firstArgument);

            Console.WriteLine("enter magic nr 2: ");
            var secondArgument = Console.ReadLine();
            yourSecondMagicNumber = Int32.Parse(secondArgument);
        }
        else
        {
            yourFirstMagicNumber = Int32.Parse(args[0]);
            yourSecondMagicNumber = Int32.Parse(args[1]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You beat me to it, I had the same suggestion :-)